# centOS: Installed programs are gone after reboot

Tags: centos

Hi I downloaded CentOS 6 live cd and installed the iso into a VM. When I install applications:

```
yum install git
```

The program git is installed, but after reboot the system no longer has git.
Am I installing the OS wrong? Do I need to burn it to a disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're still booting from the live cd image, thus your changes have only been saved in your system memory, and not actually written to disk.

If you've actually installed it detach the .iso from the virtual machine and give booting it another shot.